# Build docker image from specific layer of image

Tags: docker

**What I want**

I have a Dockerfile that no longer builds because some of its initial build steps rely on services that are no longer available, and would be a pain to reverse-engineer.  This whole thing will be rewritten soon, but for now I would like to just rebuild the the image with a fix from a layer that contains the problem step.

My Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN this_thing_that_breaks
RUN apt-get install etc
COPY blah
```

I essentially want to use the 3rd layer as my base layer and build on top of that.

**What I have done**

1. Pull the working image from repo:  `docker pull ecr/my-image:cache`
2. `docker build --cache-from ecr/my-image:cache -t ecr/my-image:fix .`

At this point I expected my build to use the existing layers from `:cache` to build `:fix`, but my build started from scratch and failed.

[This layer explanation post](https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/) seems to say that after `1.10` docker images ship with all of its layers as a whole, and those layers aren't really accessible anymore.
However, when I look at `docker inspect ecr/my-image:cache`, I see a whole bunch of layers' sha256 ids.  Which again makes me think that there should be a way to point at a specific layer and use that as the cache's base.

Is it possible to build a docker image given a list of layers' sha256 ids?

I plan on nuking this after I've fixed it, so elegance isn't a necessity here.

**Extra info**

```
$ docker version
Version:           18.09.1
API version:       1.39
OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a specific layer of an image as base of another image, it is possible to directly use the layer's SHA256 hash in `FROM` instruction.

For example, say you have this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN this_thing_that_breaks
RUN apt-get install etc
COPY blah
```

and already have an image successfully built from this Dockerfile (at that time, `this_thing_that_breaks` worked). `RUN this_thing_that_breaks` stopped working recently and we are unable to build the image now.

Say, the already built image is tagged `my-image:cache`. To find the SHA256 id of the exact layer which breaks, run `docker history my-image:cache` and note down the SHA256 id (the one corresponding to `RUN this_thing_that_breaks` here).

Say the SHA256 id noted down is `066a73a3a0c4`. Now remove all the instructions before `RUN this_thing_that_breaks` and replace it with `FROM 066a73a3a0c4`.

```
FROM 066a73a3a0c4
RUN apt-get install etc
COPY blah
```

Now, build the new image `my-image:fix` using `docker build --cache-from my-image:cache -t my-image:fix .`. Now, this should use the specific breaking layer  which is already cached as the base image for creating the new image.

Hope this helps!

**Previous Answer:**

The reason why cache is not used could be that `ubuntu:14.04` image in `ecr/my-image:cache` and locally cached `ubuntu:14.04` image are not same as described here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26065#issuecomment-249046559

> If the `FROM` image changes, no cache is reused. This is kind of useful and actually important because otherwise, the user can not detect that there are important security fixes in the base image because they always use the cache. But this may also come as a surprise to some users. I think we should not try to make some hack to work around it, rather if some users want different behavior they should just use immutable tags or digests as a `FROM` image.

So, one option I see is to delete locally cached `ubuntu:14.04` using `docker rmi ubuntu:14.04` and then run `docker build --cache-from ecr/my-image:cache -t ecr/my-image:fix`.

I hope this works but I haven't confirmed it. If this doesn't work, I suggest checking [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31613) and check the options mentioned there.

Comment: I'm not convinced that its `ubuntu:14.04` image changing.  After purging it and rebuilding my image it does re-download it, which supports your idea, though this image has been rebuilt by TravisCI using a cached version successfully, which is the same image that I've pulled.  Which alludes to the issue you linked, which doesn't really seem to be solved.

Comment: The problem ended up being using both docker and docker-compose. I posted a short answer about it.

Comment: Glad that you found the cause of the issue. :) I've updated the answer to answer your specific question - how to build docker image from specific layer of image.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work in current versions of Docker, which do not create full-blown images for each layer. (Starting with Docker 1.10 I believe)

One workaround is described in this post: https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/restore-rollback-layers-from-docker-image-a4e4b117d7e6. Just be ready to roll up your sleeves!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case was that `docker build` and `docker-compose build` [don't share the same cache](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5090)

The image was originally built with `docker-compose` and I was using straight up docker.
When using docker-compose the cached layers were used as expected.

While this does not answer the question of how to build an image from some specified layers, it did clear my roadblock.

Comment: Glad that the roadblock is cleared now. :) Coming to your question of how to build an image from specified layer, I tried giving the specific layer's sha256 id in FROM statement and it worked. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I updated my previous answer to answer this question in detail. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Bless Huzzah!  Thanks for the extra effort